# i am getting image url from json and they are loading successfully in grid view but after then scroll previous image replace by below images

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-gridview, android-scrollview

one problem in there after the scroll gridview previous image replace by below images and again scroll up its again load i want its load one time and never  be change on scroll.my app url is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vaibhavtech.mbmovies

```
public class NewMovie extends Activity {

private GridView lv;
private Vibrator vibrator;
private ArrayList<DataDemo> mDemoDataAl;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private String mStringURL = "";
private ImageLoader mImageLoader = null;

protected static final int SHOW_PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
protected static final int STOP_PROGRESS_DIALOG = 1;
protected static final int NETWORK_FAILURE = 2;
protected static final int PROBLEM_IN_CONNECTING_SERVER = 3;
protected static final int SET_ADAPTER = 4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_movie);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDemoDataAl = new ArrayList<DataDemo>();
    mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    lv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    mStringURL = "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category="
            + MainActivity.movie_Category + "&sub_category=new";

    Log.d("The Url is ", " URL : " + mStringURL);

    lv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            vibrator.vibrate(40);
            MainActivity.movie_Id = ((TextView) arg1
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_girdview_content_id)).getText()
                    .toString();
            startActivity(new Intent(NewMovie.this, MovieDescription.class));
        }
    });

    new GetDemoData().execute();
}

private class GetDemoData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(mStringURL,
                    NewMovie.this);
            if (json != null) {
                JSONArray MoviesArray = json.getJSONArray("Demo");
                for (int i = 0; i < MoviesArray.length(); i++) {
                    DataDemo mDemoData = new DataDemo();
                    mDemoData.setmDemoId(MoviesArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            .getString("id"));
                    mDemoData.setmDemoTitle(MoviesArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            .getString("title"));
                    mDemoData.setmDemoYear(MoviesArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            .getString("year"));
                    mDemoData.setmDemoDuration(MoviesArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            .getString("duration"));
                    mDemoData.setmDemoPoster(MoviesArray.getJSONObject(i)
                            .getString("poster"));
                    mDemoDataAl.add(mDemoData);
                }
            } else {
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(PROBLEM_IN_CONNECTING_SERVER);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exceptions",
                    " The Xception messages are " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
        mDemoDataAl.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SET_ADAPTER);
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(STOP_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
    }
}

public class NewMoviesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    public NewMoviesAdapter() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(NewMovie.this);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mDemoDataAl.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_view_content,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtMovieId = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_girdview_content_id);
            holder.txtMovieDuration = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_girdview_content_listner);
            holder.txtMovieName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_girdview_content_name);
            holder.txtMovieYear = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_girdview_content_like);
            holder.imgMovie = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_girdview_content_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            holder.txtMovieId.setText(Utils
                    .asUpperCaseFirstChar(mDemoDataAl.get(position)
                            .getmDemoId()));
            holder.txtMovieDuration.setText(mDemoDataAl.get(position)
                    .getmDemoDuration());
            holder.txtMovieName.setText(Utils
                    .asUpperCaseFirstChar(mDemoDataAl.get(position)
                            .getmDemoTitle()));
            holder.txtMovieYear.setText(mDemoDataAl.get(position)
                    .getmDemoYear());

            mImageLoader.displayImage(
                    "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/admin/upload/"
                            + mDemoDataAl.get(position).getmDemoPoster(),
                    holder.imgMovie);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtMovieId;
        public TextView txtMovieDuration;
        public TextView txtMovieName;
        public TextView txtMovieYear;
        public ImageView imgMovie;

    }
}

public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 5;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {

    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading
                && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            // new do.execute(currentPage + 1);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}

Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case SHOW_PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                progressDialog = Utils.createProgressDialog(NewMovie.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loding...");
                progressDialog.show();
            } else {
                progressDialog.show();
            }
            mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            break;

        case STOP_PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            mHandler.removeMessages(STOP_PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            break;

        case NETWORK_FAILURE:
            Utils.displayToast(NewMovie.this,
                    Constant.NO_NETWORK_CONNECTION);
            mHandler.removeMessages(NETWORK_FAILURE);
            break;

        case PROBLEM_IN_CONNECTING_SERVER:
            Utils.displayToast(NewMovie.this,
                    Constant.PROBLEM_IN_CONNECTING_SERVER);
            mHandler.removeMessages(PROBLEM_IN_CONNECTING_SERVER);
            break;
        case SET_ADAPTER:

            lv.setAdapter(new NewMoviesAdapter());
            mHandler.removeMessages(SET_ADAPTER);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    };
};
```

}

newmovie.xml**********************************************

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="377dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            getApplicationContext())
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
            .writeDebugLogs() // Remove for release app
            .build();
    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

}
```

Comment: pls post all code related to it.. like xml

Comment: ok  on scrolling already load previous image replace by current show load image

Comment: post your gridview xml code also and all other necessary thing like demo class i try to run on my machine and help you to solve it

Comment: email---kailash09dabhi@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

It should help you: [Universal Image Loader for Android](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). I was tried it and I can say that it's simple and practical.

Comment: thanks but i am use this already its work but on scrolling already load previous image replace by current show load image.